# Able to receive ping only from one direction between two subnets Rpi 4 buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, router, ping, iptables

I have a typical configuration where Rpi acts as an router between two subnets. One subnet is connected to Rpi eth0 and there is now laptop connected directly (one day there will be an ip-camera). Rpi connects via wlan0 to to wireless router to get an internet connection.
[Picture of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTn3n.png)

There is several instruction on the web to get this working and it almost works. I can ping devices connected to my wireless router (but not my wireless router!?), from laptop connected to Rpi. I have internet connection on laptop connected to Rpi. Problem is though that I can't ping my laptop (that is connected to Rpi) from subnet of my wireless router. Yes, it has got something to do with my iptables confuration.

Here is some data:

I have set up net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in my sysctl.conf file

I have done these settings:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

IPtables look like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  296  191K ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  eth0    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   37 14316 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   wlan0   anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Routing tabe looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 wlan0
default         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 wlan0
192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    202    0        0 eth0
```

Any other information that could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

In your wireless router routing table you should forward traffic going to 10.10.0.0/24 to the interface connected to the second subnet, the traffic going to 192.3.0.0/24 to the interface connected to the Rpi and other traffic to the interface connected to internet.
You also should have a routing table to the Subnet-1 with your Rpi as a gateway like this:

Destination     Gateway    Genmask
192.168.3.0     Rpi @IP    255.255.255.0